# How to override method when instantiating object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In Java, to override method when instantiating new object we can do this

```
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(
            MainActivity.class) {
        @Override
        protected void beforeActivityLaunched() {
            // implement code
            super.beforeActivityLaunched();
        }
    };
```

How to do that in Kotlin? I tried this code but it failed to compile.

```
@Rule @JvmField
var rule = ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java) {
    override fun beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched()
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @NihalSaxena It won't compile, the IDE says Type mismatch and Unresolved reference.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you want to create anonymous inner class, you should use `object`.

```
var rule = object : ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity::class.java) {
    override fun beforeActivityLaunched() {
        super.beforeActivityLaunched()
    }
}
```

See also [Object Expressions and Declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html).