# Can not override getParam in Kotlin (Volley)

Tags: android, kotlin, post, android-volley

I can not override `getParam` like shown below. I hope someone can explain how to override `getParam` in Kotlin.

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

[image]

```
fun testpost(button: Button)
{
    val url = "http://192.168.178.23/insertcode.php"
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)


    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            { response ->
                button.text = "Response is: ${response}"
            },
            { button.text = "That didn't work!" })
    {
        override fun getParam(){

        }
    }
    queue.add(stringRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing object before StringRequest and now the method getParams is available.

The code looks like this:

```
fun testpost(button: Button)
    {
        val url = "http://192.168.178.23/insertcode.php"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)


        val stringRequest = object :StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            { response ->
                button.text = "Response is: ${response}"
            },
            { button.text = "That didn't work!" })
        {
            //Press Ctr + O to find getParams
            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
                hashMap.put("name", "peter")
                return hashMap
            }
        }
        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }
```

Comment: This works too as you are not boxing it in to the `StringRequest` class but rather to the underlying `Response` class which exposes `getParams`. +1 for simplicity

Comment: No problem Sorry * `Request` class not `Response`.

Comment: Here's a nice post on it with a link to more https://stackoverflow.com/a/44604198/1133011 to better explain "anonymous inner classes'

Comment: Mark you answer as the solution its much more simple mate and probably the way to go!

Comment: Ok I will but thanks for your time and the explaining! (Can accpect own answers after 2 days)

Comment: Thanks so much. Couldn't find this answer anywhere.  And when I tried CTRL-O it suggests getPostParams (see image where I searched: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjgEO.png) then when I added it, it says that getPostParams is deprecated.   I was 100% confused by that.  Glad you had this answer.  Even the official Volley docs have _nothing_ on POST - only have info an examples for GET.  Crazy.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, it's not exposed in `StringRequest` or any other built in request for that matter. If that's indeed what you need to do, you have to unfortunately [create your own custom request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom).

Below is an example for a Custom `StringRequest` which allows us to specify `params` in its constructor (*Kotlin*):

```
import androidx.annotation.GuardedBy
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
import java.nio.charset.Charset

class CustomStringRequest(
    method: Int,
    url: String,
    listener: Response.Listener<String>,
    errorListener: Response.ErrorListener?,
    private val params: MutableMap<String, String>
) : Request<String>(method, url, errorListener) {

    private val lock = Any()

    @GuardedBy("lock")
    private var listener: Response.Listener<String>? = listener

    override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return params
    }

    override fun cancel() {
        super.cancel()
        synchronized(lock) { listener = null }
    }

    override fun deliverResponse(response: String) {
        var listener: Response.Listener<String>?
        synchronized(lock) { listener = this.listener }
        if (listener != null) {
            listener!!.onResponse(response)
        }
    }

    override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<String> {
        val parsed: String = try {
            String(response.data, Charset.forName(HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response?.headers)))
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            // Since minSdkVersion = 8, we can't call
            // new String(response.data, Charset.defaultCharset())
            // So suppress the warning instead.
            String(response.data)
        }

        return Response.success(
            parsed,
            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response)
        )
    }
}
```

You would then use it like:

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
val url = "YOUR_URL"

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
val stringRequest = CustomStringRequest(
    Request.Method.POST, url,
    Response.Listener { response ->
        // TODO do something with response
    },
    Response.ErrorListener {
        // TODO handle errors
    },
    hashMapOf("name" to "value") // TODO add your params here
)

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest)
```

Comment: Please see updated answer, added an example and fixed up the code a bit too.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your fast answer. I tested your code and it works very good! I searched a bit too and came to an option I will share but don't understand 100%.